# Create isolated environment for user

Tags: arch-linux, chroot

I personally use Hyprland and keep everything pretty light.

Unfortunately, that's not really conducive to my girlfriend being able to use my computer, so I really need to install something like KDE that's normal person friendly.

I don't really want to just install KDE and then use Hyprland on my account and KDE on hers because these DEs are very leaky and I'll end up with a bunch of crap running that I don't want, without a huge amount of effort. So, I want to create a completely isolated environment for her.

What would be the best way to do this? I could think of a way to do it with `chroot` but then I'm not entirely sure how I could tie that in with my DM and I'm also not sure what limitations that would place on it wrt what does and doesn't work in a `chroot` but as long as firefox, steam, and games run we should be fine.

Is there a better way to do this than `chroot` with a bunch of scripts to tie it into my DM?

---

I've just given it a go with the `chroot` approach, and the first issue I've ran into is there's no dbus in the `chroot` so `startplasma-wayland` fails.

Comment: "*because these DEs are very leaky and I'll end up with a bunch of crap running that I don't want,*" Are you familiar with the term "Fear, uncertainty and doubt"? Because, if you don't start KDE, KDE won't run. Of course, as soon as you realize that, say, the KDE contact manager is neat, and you start that in your Hyprland, it might start its data server and that might start other KDE services. But you don't seem interested in that, so there's no problem.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's based in false claims.

Comment: I mean, let's take the *fear* out of this! You have a linux distro. It's trivial to install and uninstall KDE: So install KDE and start your usual Hyprland session. Does KDE run? If not, then your girlfriend running a KDE session will have zero effect on your session. If it is, we can look into it. If it turns out to be a problem, it's still just a `pacman` (or whatever one should use on arch) command to get rid of it!

Comment: Nowadays, instead of directly using `chroot`, I would suggest using one of the rootless containers approach, such as [`apptainer`](https://apptainer.org/)(Formarly known as [`singularity`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_(software))) or to some extent [`podman`](https://podman.io/). They make it easier to create a chroot image, run it, and provide more flexibility and granularity in namespace separation. For instance, you can decide if you want to use different network namespace, user namespace etc. This will also solve your `dbus` issue.